# how to redirect to one other method spring controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to know how to redirect  a return from a method to one other method in a @RestController.
I know with a normal Controller is return "redirect:/method" but with rest controller doesn't work

this is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

@GetMapping("/list")
    public Page<PasswordUser> showUsers(Pageable pageable){


        return userService.showUsers(pageable);

    }

@PostMapping ("/blockUnblockUser")
    public String blockOrUnblockUser(@RequestParam(name = "id")long id  )  {



        PasswordUser user=userService.getUserById(id);
        userService.blockUnblockUser(user);

        return "redirect to list method";

    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: ,you have to change the controller signature from RestController to Controller

Answer (score 2):

You can `return "redirect:/path/to/redirect"` from your view as follows:

```
@PostMapping ("/blockUnblockUser")
public String blockOrUnblockUser(@RequestParam(name = "id")long id  ) {
    PasswordUser user=userService.getUserById(id);
    userService.blockUnblockUser(user);

    return "redirect:/admin/list";
}
```

Comment: Thank you in fact I need a RestController , i know with controller it works, but i would like to know if is a possiblitie to redirect a method with a restController.The application will be inmplemented in a restfull service